# Fill the gap between door plate and slab

Tags: doors, exterior, gap

Thank you for reading my question.
I replaced our front door awhile back and everything went ok. It's a 36" exterior door with one side light, prehung.
After the door was in, leveled and screwed in place I realized that the bottom sill (plate?) and the concrete slab had a big gap.
[image]
Turns out that the new door has a sill with a slope, but the bottom of the whole prehung door box is flat, but the concrete under the door had a slope.
So now I'm left with a gap. The door is sealed on the bottom on the inside but as the slope grows, so does my gap. I filled the gap with a 1x6 PT cut at an angled the long way, but the gap wary a little from left to right so it's not perfect.
Could I fill this gap with self leveling concrete? Some kind of foam that holds up to the constant stepping on the door sill? Any other ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think if you were to use the self leveling concrete you should take the door off

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to remove the door to apply leveling compound; builders filler is probably you best bet, This is a two part plastic putty that adheres well and sets very hard, it can be tinted using oxide powder, or painted etc.

It has a strong chemical smell that will dissapear after a few weeks.

Comment: I went to the local hardware store and the guy suggested Rockite and a big bag (like a supersized cake decorating back) mix it quickly and squezze it under the door.

Comment: It worked, but you have to be very fast, it dries in minutes so once you get it under the door you have to squeeze it all out, rinse the bag, make a new small batch and repeat. Maybe mortar would have been better. But it looks good now.

Comment: @Bamse I'm glad this worked for you. Please click the check-mark next to this answer so others will know there's a good solution for it!